# Excel VBA Office 2011 - Any ideas of how to Send/Receive DatagramPacket?

Tags: macos, vba, excel, udp

I've been looking around for a way to send/receive Datagrams using VBA in Excel 2011 for Mac. I was capable of sending a message doing:

```
Function sendDatagramPacket(message As String)
    system ("echo foo | nc -4u -w1 localhost 3000") End Function
```

Anyway, trying to establish a real connection doing something like this:

`system ("nc localhost 1234")` might work to establish the connection, but is there any way to receive the messages being sent? Or any better way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I noticed you are on mac - so this article probably won't help but have you had a look? http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?524835-Send-UDP-Packets-in-VBA
You'd have to find the equivalent os libraries that allow you to do what you need.

Comment: The example of that link doesn't work at all... :/

Comment: loading win32 dll's on a mac wouldn't work, that is correct.